# system security needs classification

Tags: exploit, openvas

I am working on a way to classify our systems (everything that is reacheable through ip) on how bad it would be and how possible it is, that someone would get unauthorized access using exploits.

I do this to determine how deep and how often I am going to check them with vulnaribility scanners like OpenVAS.

So far I have the following criteria:

- Are there any plaintext credentials on the affected system or files which can be decrypted easily to get access to other systems?
- Do users on the affected system have special rights to connect and authenticate to other systems?
- Is there any personal-related data on the system?
- Does the loss of the system affect other systems which rely on it too?
- Is it costly in time or money to replace the system if an attacker destroys it or makes it useless (Software)?
- Is it a productive or just a demo/test system?
- Is only a sole department concerned with the temporal loss of the system or multiple ones?
- Does the affected department rely invariably on the system or is it possibly to maintain operability over a short time without the system?
- Does the configuration and software on the system change often, so it´s more likely that misconfigurations happen or new vulnerabilities get patched into the system?
- Is it a physical system or a virtual machine?

I would appreciate if someone has a point or two to add or if theres already a standard for classifying systems that way.

Comment: the term you are looking for is "Risk Analysis"

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you might be looking for some of what is covered in the CERT-RMM.

http://www.cert.org/resilience/products-services/cert-rmm/index.cfm

I suspect the scope of the Resilience Management Model may exceed your current project but the objective you describe appears to be part way down the path of what RMM codifies.  One other tangental benefit is that you can point to the work that you are doing as following a documented and promulgated system.